# Ant design rc-time-picker position wrong on Modal with animation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, antd

```
  <div>
    <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}>Open</Button>
    <Modal
      show={this.state.show}
      onHide={() => this.setState({ show: false })}
      animation={true}
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <TimePicker open getPopupContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentNode}/>
        <div style={{ height: '370px' }} />
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  </div>
```

With animation enabled, it becomes https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq0Kp.png

Without animation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGk0Y.png

[image: Edit ryj98no4xn]

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: I see both displaying correctly (like the image without animation) what browser are you using?

Comment: @Kossel Chrome V60. Seems like it only breaks on a certain combination of window size and div height. Try resizing your window or adjust the `<div style={{ height: '370px' }} />` then close and open the modal again. I'm on 2048x1152

Comment: I'm using Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit), it still looks good :S, do you have any chrome plugins that may inject css?

Comment: nope, it breaks on firefox as well so not browser problem. did you try adjusting the style height value, then closing and opening the modal again?

Comment: is the the intented look https://imgur.com/y2FiKUN

Comment: @Kossel yes that's correct. I have reduced the height so it should break on smaller screen now, try it again (remember to close the modal and reopen after resizing ur window). https://i.imgur.com/VNEjM5C.png